# Sencha slidable nav menu

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm new to sensha, and I'm not sure which elements to use for this, but I'm hoping someone can help me by telling me the class names of what I'm looking for.

Anyway, here's the idea:

I want to do a two "view" layout.

top view: a "view" which holds a nav. That nav would be the equiv of a  with several

elements inside. This would be an hbox and I'd like it to be draggable left-right, but I'm not sure how do to that.

bottom view: would show after and item from the top view is selected

The other question is how I would I would switch between "view" 1 and "view" 2.

I realize this is a noobish question, but I'll be doing research in the mean time to see if I can answer this question myself. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the top "view":

I've filled a container with smaller containers (buttons). on the main container I added scroll:'horizontal' and viola. Help this helps someone!